# swiftでiOS-chartsを導入したい。

Tags: swift, xcode

質問は表題の通りです。

```
http://qiita.com/satoken0417/items/479bcdf91cff2634ffb1
```

を参考にiso-chartsを導入しようと思いました。
cocoa podsまでは問題なく出来たのですが、
サンプルコードをXcodeにコピペしたところ、

```
import UIKit
import Charts
class ViewController: UIViewController {
```

の最初の部分のimport ChartsでNo such module 'Charts'とエラーが出ます。

原因は、DLしたCharts-masterをXcodeにインストールしていないからだと思います。
ですが、
このCharts-masterをどんな方法でXcodeにインストールすれば良いのか？がわかりません。
ググっても具体的な方法が見当たりません。

すみませんが、どなたか解る方がいらっしゃいましたらご指導いただけないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

先日cocoapodsからiOS Chartsを入れました。

ライブラリを入れてみたけど警告が出てしまっているということですね。

警告が出たあとビルドは一度もされていないと推察します。
普通は警告が出たら問題の箇所を探すとは思いますがダメ元で一度ビルドしてみてください。
 私も同じ状況になったので色々試したのですが最後に何も考えずにビルドしたらあっけなく成功した、ということがありましたので参考までに。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。